# When will change in one class be reflected on another class?

Tags: python, class

I have 2 classes. The second class receive the first class as a parameter during class object initialization. The code is:

```
import random

class DataSet(object):
    def __init__(self, num):
        self.num=num
        self.data = self._gen_data()

    def _gen_data(self):

        return random.sample(list(range(100)), self.num)

    def regenerate_data(self):
        self.data = self._gen_data()

    def show_data(self):
        print(self.data)

class DataLoader(object):
    def __init__(self, dataset):
        self.data = dataset.data
    def show_all_data(self):
        print(self.data)



mydata = DataSet(num=5)
mydata.show_data()

myloader = DataLoader(dataset=mydata)
myloader.show_all_data()

mydata.regenerate_data()
mydata.show_data()

myloader.show_all_data()
```

If I use the `regenerate_data()` method of `mydata`, I expect that the DataLoader object will also show the changed data. But apparently, I was wrong.
The change in `mydata` is not reflected on `myloader`, which still shows the old data.

Then I construct a second example,

```
import random

class DataSet(object):
    def __init__(self, num):
        self.num=num
        self.data = self._gen_data()

    def _gen_data(self):    
        return random.sample(list(range(100)), self.num)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.data[index]

    def regenerate_data(self):
        self.data = self._gen_data()

    def show_data(self):
        print(self.data)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)

class DataLoader(object):
    def __init__(self, dataset):
        self.dataset = dataset

    def show_batch(self):
        print([self.dataset[i] for i in [0, 1]])

mydata = DataSet(num=5)
mydata.show_data()

myloader = DataLoader(dataset=mydata)
myloader.show_batch()

mydata.regenerate_data()
mydata.show_data()

myloader.show_batch()
```

Now change in `mydata` object is reflected on `myloader`.

My question is, why in the first example, the change in first class is not reflected on second class, while in the second example, change in first class will be reflected on second class? Is there some rule?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first example, `regenerate_data()` only returns newly generated data, it doesn't assign it to anything. In your second example, since `myloader` holds a reference to `mydata`, changing an attribute in `mydata` by assigning it, also changes it in `myloader`, because they refference the same object.

Edit: here is how you can test that your classes are indeed mutable;

```
class ExampleClass:

    def __init__(self):
        self.data = 'foo'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.data

example = ExampleClass()
example.data = 'bar'
print(example)
```

What does this tell you?

Comment: Just let me know if its unclear or if you need some further elaborating.

Comment: so if I have a `change_data()`  method for `mydata` which changes the `data` element in `mydata`, this change will be reflected also on `myloader`, right? What if the `data` member of `mydata` is immutalbe type such as tuple, then change in `data` will not be reflected on `myloader`.

Comment: @jdhao It doesn't really matter if it is immutable, for example, I can do `x = (1, 2)`, and then later do `x = (3, 2)`. This will change the value of `x`, which indeed is immutable. What immutable implies, is that you can't change elements separately, you can only reassign it, for example `x[0] = 3` will not work.

Comment: yes, that is what I mean. Since immutable type can not change. If we change its reference. Then `myloader` will can not reflect this change. Also, I am curious if the two custom class is mutable or immutable. Is there a method to test it?

Comment: @jdhao I think you misunderstood. The attribute can be immutable, but it doesn't matter, you can still change it, you just can't *mutate* it. **Reassigning** it is completely fine. Edit: both of your custom classes are *mutable*.

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer: bad answer. See the other one.**

In the first example, you're using this: `self.data = dataset.data`, and `dataset.data` is a new list generated by the function `random.sample`. While it's true that if you do `list1 = list2` you are pointing to the same list with 2 variables, with `random.sample` you create a new one, with no other variables containing it, so if you generate another one, in `self.data` you'll still have the one you generated before because it's the only variable pointing to that list.

In your second example you store the object you instantiated, not a copy, so the opposite happens: both variables point to the same object, and if you modify the attributes of the class using one of those two variables, you'll get the same attributes if you get them from the other one.

Comment: The first you say is correct, but he actually stores a reference to the same object in both cases, but only in the second the new data is actually assigned to something.

Comment: hm you're right, I think I supposed that `random.sample()` returned a generator, not a list, and that's why I said it didn't return the same list but a different one.